# Is it possible to edit a comment?

Tags: support, comments, edits

Is it possible to edit my own comments?

I've been able to edit a comment, I think, but I went back to a comment posted earlier and don't see a way to edit it now, but rather only delete it.

Comment: Within 5 minutes of posting the comment only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing (*own*) comments is possible and allowed for only a period of 5 minutes after they are posted. AFAIK, there's no limit on number of times the edit is allowed but it's *speed-limited* (*only edit a comment / 5sec or similar*).

In case you have a comment that you *need* to edit and *need* to be present, you can always remove the existing one and add a new one.

Comment: Replacing comment with a new one is only actual for latest comment. In other case chain of messages could be broken.

Comment: @alexolut very correct, but sometimes, to _make sense_ we may need to do that. That is why I made those _need_ s _italics_. Overall, comments are second class citizen and not expected to be present forever, any way.

Comment: ... and could be moved to the chat :)